# Draw circuit with labels

Tags: circuitikz

I want to create the following circuit
[image]

Can someone help me because I have no much experience with Latex. Especially, how can I obtain the yellow colour in the right hand side of the picture. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you are using circuitikz, see pages 40-41 and 196 of the manual for fill colors.  Any component can be implemented as a node.  Labels with arrows can be implemented as separate nodes (TikZ),

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200935/arrows-and-label-for-equivalent-resistance-with-circuitikz for example.

Comment: Show us what you try so far. Adding color to "lichtquelle" (light bulb) is not big problem ....

Comment: @wayne -- for the yellow color lamp please see 
 -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/544692/197451

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: Following @Rmano's comment, I updated the answer inserting `\usepackage{circuitikz-1.4.6}`. With this version, the `fill` option worked fine. Figure has also been updated.*

A MWE follows. You can choose between the internal label or the alternative with external labels from node and line connecting them to the elements.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz-1.4.6}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw (0,0) to[normal open switch, *-*, l=Schalter, name=C] ++(0.6,0) -- ++(1.5,0)
  to[lamp, l=Lichtquelle, name=L, fill=yellow] ++(0,-2)
  -| ++(-3.5,0.5)
  to[battery2, l=Spannungquelle, name=S, invert] ++(0,+1) 
  |- (0,0);

% Alternative to l
\draw (-2.5,-2) node[below]{Spannungquelle} -- (S);
\draw (0.3,1) node[above]{Schalter} -- (C);
\draw (2.8,-2) node[below]{Lichtquelle} -- (L);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Manually drawn arrows are the alternative ones.

[image]

Comment: Which version are you using?  If I compile your code I have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2VXn.png with a yellow lamp.

Comment: @Rmano, Checking MikTeX console, CircuitikZ version I have is 1.4.6. I searched inside the LaTeX folders, and there are many `circuitikz` `.sty` files. So I added the version `\usepackage{circuitikz-1.4.6}` and now `fill` applies colors. I will update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: that means that you have some "stranded" file with an older version. Please, add `This is \pgfcircversion{} on \pgfcircversiondate` just after the `\begin{document}`, check the version printed and find in the `.log` which file has been really inputted.

Comment: @Rmano, indeed, versions change accordingly to the `\usepackage`. I have no idea what MikTeX did. I will check it in depth. Thanks.